Adjoint of an operator is compact implies operator is compact
The question is to show that given an operator $T\in\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H},\mathcal{K})$ whose adjoint $T^*$ is compact, then $T$ must also be compact. $\mathcal{B}_0(\mathcal{H},\mathcal{K})$ denotes the set of compact operators from Hilbert spaces $\mathcal{H}\mapsto\mathcal{K}$, and $ball\ \mathcal{H}$ is the closed unit ball in $\mathcal{H}$. I have a proof but I'm not totally confident its correct:
Assume $T\in\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H},\mathcal{K})$ and $T^*\in\mathcal{B}_0(\mathcal{H},\mathcal{K})$. $T^*(ball \ \mathcal{H}) = \{T^*h\in\mathcal{K}:||h||\leq1, \ h\in  ball \ \mathcal{H}\}$. Since $||T||=||T^*||\leq C \in\mathbb{R}^+$, $||Th||=||T^*h||$ for all $h\in ball\ \mathcal{H}$. Let $\varepsilon>0$. Then
$$T(ball\ \mathcal{H}) \subseteq\{Th:||Th||\leq C-\varepsilon, \ h\in ball\ \mathcal{H}\} = \{T^*h:||T^*h||\leq C-\varepsilon, \ h\in ball\ \mathcal{H}\}\subseteq \text{cl}[T^*(ball \ \mathcal{H})]$$
as $\varepsilon\to0$, where $\text{cl}[T^*(ball \ \mathcal{H})]$ is compact. Since the closure of any subspace of a compact space is compact, cl[$T(ball \ \mathcal{H})$] is compact.
If someone could verify that this is right or tell me where I went wrong I'd really appreciate it.

Easier proof: $T^{**}$, an extension of $T$, is compact.

sorry, wdym by extension? ;-;

Actually, $T^{**}=T$ since you are in Hilbert spaces. My comment works for Banach spaces.

Let $S=T^*.$ Then $S:\mathcal{K}\to \mathcal{H}.$ The operator $S^*S:\mathcal{K}\to \mathcal{K}$ is positive. Let $|S|$ denote the square root of $S^*S.$ Then $S=U|S|,$ where $U$ is a partial isometry $U: \mathcal{K}\to \mathcal{H}$ defined by $U(|S|x)=Sx$ and $Ux=0$ for $x\perp |S|(\mathcal{K}).$ Then $U^*S=|S|.$ Since $S=T^*$ is compact, so is $|S|.$ On the other hand $S^*=(U|S|)^*=|S|U^*.$ Thus $T=S^*$ is compact as well.
